# Firebase inicio automatico mediante usuario administrador

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Estoy haciendo una app con Android Studio y java, la parte de la base de datos funciona mediante Firebase.
Estoy intentando iniciar sesión con mi usuario administrador, una vez inicio me carga la pantalla de inicio la cual tiene una **variable de usuario** y accede con esa, me gustaría en ese mismo if añadir la comparación con mi usuario administrador. **Pero no se como coge los usuarios la funcion "getCurrentUser" no se si es una ID o es el correo.**

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (vAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {  // if(vAuth.getCurrentUser() != "admin@admin.com")

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, IniciadoAdminActivity.class));
        finish();

    }
}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que deberias hacer es crear una referencia al usuario que esta logueado en ese momento y acceder a sus propiedades en la base de datos

Por ejemplo, si en la base de datos tienes a tu usuario cargado de la siguiente manera

```
User 
|__ user_id
          |__ nombre: "Pepe"
          |__ isAdmin: true
```

Luego deberias acceder en tu metodo a este dato del usuario para poder decidir si el usuario es admin o no

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (vAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {  // if(vAuth.getCurrentUser() != "admin@admin.com")

        mDatabaseRef.child("User").child(vAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addListenerForSingleValue {
           public void onDataChange(dataSnapshot...) {
             if(dataSnapshot.child("isAdmin").getValue() == true){
              // Es admin
             }else{
               startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, IniciadoAdminActivity.class));
        finish();

              }
    }
}
```

Asi deberia ser la logica para diferenciar un usuario de un administrador, este pseudocodigo te va a servir para programar la logica

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hice con Firebase pero desde web app, lo voy a hacer en Android Studio en estos días.

Lo que hice (en javascript) y debe ser parecido en java:
Una función que lea el estado de logueado sí/no que active, en caso de login, una función que compare el UID del usuario con el del administrador. Se evita así leer el UID del administrador en la base de datos...

```
// Leer estado autentificado - no autentificado
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  console.log(user)
  if (user) {
    console.log("Usuario logueado")
    alertaAdmin(user.uid)
  }
});

function alertaAdmin(uid) {
  var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
  console.log("function alertaAdmin activada")
  if (uid == "P4vQc3iYeJZqJzVUC2qfsQzkc9") {
    console.log("El usuario es administrador")
    funcionesExclusivasAdministrador()
  } else {
    console.log("El usuario es usuario común")
  }
}
```

Requisito es cargar con antelación los datos de la autenticación en la base de datos para luego consultarlos...